# How to capture and use color intensity as an attribute in geometry nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes

So I am in Blender 3.6 and have this procedural terrain material, and I would now like to use geometry nodes to take the color of the material, select out the green areas, and then do a series of distribute points on faces, instance on points, etc to put grass and trees in those green spots so that the more solidly green it is, the denser the foliage on those areas.
The stuff with the plants I know how to do once I can isolate the data, however, I am not sure how to get the color data I need to start the whole process.

I have used the capture attribute node for other things, but not color before, and after messing around with different nodes in different arrangements, I still haven't figured out the node set up needed to get it to select the amount of a specific color and output that as a value I can plug into other things. I have tried the blender wiki and a number of youtube tutorials but nobody seems to have a good explanation of this specific need.

How can I get geometry nodes to apply a chain of nodes depending on the intensity of the green in the material?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: We need more info on your setup, for example if the color is calculated in a shader, then geonodes can't just read it - as shaders are evaluated further down the chain than geometry. Sometimes the solution is impossible (like when you use shader to color), but usually it comes down to copying/moving your shader algorithm into geonodes.

Comment: As @MarkusvonBroady says, we need information on your setup and most probably it is necessary to copy the procedural texture setup in your _Geometry Nodes_ nodetree. Then it also depends on the density of your mesh. In my answer here I give an example (I tend to think your question is kind of a duplicate then): [Mesh to points selected from material](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/286104/mesh-to-points-selected-from-material/286106#286106)

Comment: Hello TheyMightBe .. welcome to BSE. I'm going to close this on the assumption it is a duplicate, although it's not easy to tell, for sure, because we don't have enough detail. If you feel it's not a duplicate, please provide the detail, showing us, for example, where the colour of the mesh is stored.. in a map, ... on the vertices .... and we can re-open